# How do you detect sneaking in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am wondering if it is possible to detect sneaking in Minecraft Bedrock.

Answer (score 3):

## No

In the vanilla game via command you cannot tell.

## Another Way?

You may be able to tell with a `player.json` modification with a behavior pack, and then what you can do could be some kind of weird detection system. I will not explain this, you will have to learn about *component groups* and *behavior packs.*

Answer (score -1):

You could use sculk sensors that detect non-crouching movement, then if you want the contraption to work when someone is crouching, you could use a circuit that turns off a redstone torch powering the contraption when they aren't sneaking. If they aren't moving, this won't work as it'll only tell if they are moving.

You are unable to do this via commands.

Comment: OP is asking how to detect sneaking, a contraption like that will activate also when a player is not moving, or even not present at all